# Animate a cube turning via mathematics (Java)

Tags: java, animation, 3d

For a school project i have made a program that can solve a rubiks cube (you know, that cube with all the colors). But now my teachers asked if i could do some research and try out 3d animation for one of the sides. But they want to see the mathematical way to do it. I have found a way to move the corners with the use of polar coordinates. But i do not know how i could render a cube in 3d and be able to animate it.

So my question is: how can i render things like a cube in 3d (or are there any good libraries for it) and how could i use these polar coordinates to animate it?
And is there a good tutorial out there for java 3d rendering?

i must say that i have absolutely no experience with 3d rendering, so it might be a bit difficult. But i really would like to try it out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to take an existing implementation or if you want to build code for 3D animations from scratch, you might try [this tutorial](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html). Graphics programming in this area can be quite involved; a full answer of the question is beyond the scope of this site. However, there are a few main areas.

1. Usage of vector math for transformation of objects (translation, rotation). This can be done directly or via projective geometry using 4-by-4 matrices. The latter is easier for concatenation of transformations.
2. Backface culling to remove faces of the object which cannot be seen by the camera.
3. Using a projection and a camera model to transform 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates.
4. Using a rasterizer to render the 3D vector information to the screen. Here [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at one of the 3D libraries. One that I've used a lot and found to be excellent is [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) (JME) which is designed for games but would work well for your needs. It also has an excellent tutorial that takes you from basic to very complex. In fact the first step in the tutorial is a revolving coloured cube!

JME takes a huge amount of the work out of 3D modelling. You build a scene in code with materials, lights etc. and JME does all the work to render it. You can even build your models in a tool such as [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) so you don't even need to do the modelling in code. But I will warn you that using modelling tools is definitely not for the faint hearted.